# Get error on database insert

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm using nodeJS with the [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) module and i have to do some simple queries but i can't understand how can i catch errors on insert queries. That's my sample code:

```
 pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
        client.query("INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES ('lol')");
        res.json({'err':0,'message':'successful insert'});
});
```

I would like to add a `res.json({'err':1,'message':'ERRROR'});` in case of error during the query.

Comment: See this  : - https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres#user-content-client-instance (_Read documents carefully and save your time_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to example in github page: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres
Screenshot: http://joxi.ru/K823gg6Uvx3D2O

Try this:

```
 pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
   if(err) {
     console.log('Cannot connect!', err);
     return;
   }

   client.query("INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES ('lol')", [], function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
        res.json({'err':1,'message':'ERRROR'});
        return;
      }
      res.json({'err':0,'message':'successful insert'});
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very match, i couldn't find that callback with my googling